# Symfony3 inheritance

Tags: symfony, inheritance

Using `FOSUB` i created 3 entities, the first is user which extends from FOSBaseuser and then i have Guardian (can't use parent) and Etablissement, these two extend from user, knowing that parent and etablissement are also roles when i register and pick the role, it only fills user table, i want to get rid of user table and fill the other two tables, what should i do please. I wanted to try `@MappedSuperclass` but i don't know how to make it work with two entities, when i register i get this error:

> (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
>       An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.username AS username_1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical_2, t0.email AS
>   email_3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical_4, t0.enabled AS
>   enabled_5, t0.salt AS salt_6, t0.password AS password_7, t0.last_login
>   AS last_login_8, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_9,
>   t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_10, t0.roles AS
>   roles_11 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ?' with params
>   ["aa"]:
>
> ```
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'allforkids.user' doesn't exist)
> ```

Any clue how i could fix it

Comment: Have you updated your database after the changes? `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --force --complete`

Comment: yes i did it...